# C# function to return the implemented interface of a type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, factory

I have this singleton factory class example, where I used a dictionary and determine the relevant report class at runtime.. because there are up to 40 combinations based on what each report service also has to do.

```
public sealed class ReportServiceFactory : IGetReportServices
{
    private static readonly ReportServiceFactory instance = new ReportServiceFactory();

    private static readonly Dictionary<Tuple<ReportTypes, ReportPeriodTypes>, IServiceReports> reportEntityServices =
        new Dictionary<Tuple<ReportTypes, ReportPeriodTypes>, IServiceReports> {
            { Tuple.Create(ReportTypes.Foo, ReportPeriodTypes.Week), new FooService<FooWeekEntity>() },
            { Tuple.Create(ReportTypes.Foo, ReportPeriodTypes.Month), new FooService<FooMonthEntity>() },

            { Tuple.Create(ReportTypes.Bar, ReportPeriodTypes.Week), new BarService<BarWeekEntity>() },
            { Tuple.Create(ReportTypes.Bar, ReportPeriodTypes.Month), new BarService<BarMonthEntity>() }
        };

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static ReportServiceFactory()
    {
    }

    private ReportServiceFactory()
    {
    }

    public static ReportServiceFactory Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public IServiceReports Get(ReportTypes reportType, ReportPeriodTypes periodType)
    {
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ReportTypes), reportType))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("reportType");
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ReportPeriodTypes), periodType))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("periodType");

        var reportTuple = Tuple.Create(reportType, periodType);

        if (!reportEntityServices.ContainsKey(reportTuple))
            return null;

        return reportEntityServices[reportTuple];
    }
}
```

I want to be able to return a more specific interface for the `Get()` function on the factory, to change it to `IServiceFooReports` at execution time as an example... this is so I have access to the below `FooViewModel` `Get()` function **without casting the result in other calling code.**

```
public interface IServiceFooReports : IServiceReports
{
    IEnumerable<FooViewModel> Get();
}

public class FooService<T> : IServiceFooReports
{
      ... use EF model context and call .CreateObjectContext<T>()
      do filtering on the IQueryable result and return the result materialised as the relevant view models
}
```

Is this possible? here is the `IGetReportServices` interface in case that also needs changing. `IServiceReports` is empty and currently only being used as a way to store these report services in the same dictionary... a marker interface?

```
public interface IGetReportServices
{
    IServiceReports Get(ReportTypes reportType, ReportPeriodTypes reportPeriodType);
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an object that is cast as an IGetReportServices insterface to return an IServiceFooReports without casting, then you can add a method on the interface that does the casting for you.  Any sort of tricks where you define a "new" method to change the return type will not return the more specific type if the service instance is cast as your interface.

```
IServiceReports GetFoo(..., ...);
```

with an implementation like

```
public IServiceFooReports GetFoo(ReportTypes reportType, ReportPeriodTypes reportPeriodType){
    return this.Get(reportType, reportPeriodType) As IServiceFooReports;
}
```

Alternately, you can use a generic method like

```
T Get<T>(ReportTypes reportType, ReportPeriodTypes reportPeriodType);
```

But then you need to know the class type in order to call the method so it really isn't any better than having to cast the result afterwards.  On the other hand, you can take advantage of implicit casting if you can design your report logic to use the report type instead of your ReportTypes enumeration.

```
List<T> Get<T>(T reportTemplate, ReportPeriodTypes reportPeriodType);
```

Then you could call the method like:

```
var template = new FooViewModel();
List<FooViewModel> results = Get(template, reportPeriodType);
```

Not sure if that helps

Comment: Thanks, so basically my calling code still needs to determine which function to call i.e. GetFoo, GetBar.. or what type to apply to a generic function, or just what cast I want to do :( looks like I am out of luck

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Interfaces can inherit other interfaces. When they do, you can use polymorphism to convert between the types they represent, just like when you use class inheritance. As a simple example, if you have following interfaces:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Get();
}

public interface IBar : IFoo
{
    new string Get();
}
```

and the following class:

```
public class MyClass : IBar
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return @"some data";
    }
}
```

then you can implement the following Method:

```
public MyClass SomeMethod()
{
    MyClass myVariable = new MyClass();
    return myVariable;
}
```

And call that method to populate a variable of a type defined by an interface that is not explicitly implemented by 'MyClass', but by an interface that MyClass *does* implement. i.e.,

```
IFoo myOtherVariable = SomeMethod() as IFoo;
```

NB: the point being that MyClass does not explicitly implement 'IFoo'. It only implements 'IBar', which in turn inherits 'IFoo'.

So, applying the above info to your problem, provided your interface IServiceFooReports *implements* IServiceReports, and provided the inner workings of your Method creates an object of type 'IServiceFooReports', you can return that object via the type 'IServiceReports'. Outside your method, you should be able to safely cast the output to the more specific type 'IServiceFooReports' using the 'as' keyword.

Comment: Your example relies on `SomeMethod()` returning `MyClass`. Which would be the same as my `Get()` method being defined to return a `IServiceFooReports`, which it is not. I want to have my calling code interact with the same `Get()` method on the service factory but for the return type to be more specific so I don't have to cast it or set the type in my calling code :(

Comment: There's no need for SomeMethod to return MyClass. It could also return 'IBar' or 'IFoo' and it would still work. In the case of your problem, you could instruct your method to return type 'T', where T is a type defined by an interface that is injected using generics at runtime. Provided T is castable from the specific types that the inner workings of your Method produces, all you'd need to do in your method is include a line such as 'return myResult as T' at the end of your method. All you're doing is moving where the cast happens to inside your Method.

Comment: but the compiler needs to be able to infer what T is, so my calling code would need to be like this: `.Get<IServiceFooReports>(...)` which is pretty much the same as just doing `.Get(...) as IServiceFooReports`.. I was trying to avoid this in my calling code because I then need logic in a lot of places to determine what type to use. I can't make the interface `IServiceReports` generic either because I want to store different report services in the same static dictionary inside my Factory.

Comment: Thinking about it now, changing `IServiceReports` to `IServiceReports<T>` would also force `IGetReportServices` to have to be changed to know what T is. Since the factory is a singleton I would only be able to then set one type for all the services in its dictionary. Conclusion so far is I need to refactor this project i've "inherited" so that the calling code is in less places. Thanks for the help